# Using a vector of characters that correspond to an expression as an argument to a function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following code,

```
z <- data.frame(a=sample.int(10),b=sample.int(10),c=sample.int(10))
letter <- c("a","c","b") # this will be used as the argument to a function
vec <- unlist(lapply(1:length(letter), 
              function(x) cat(paste("z[[letter[",x,"]]],",sep=""))))
vec[length(vec)] <- paste("z[[letter[",length(vec),"]]]",sep="")
```

Consequently:

```
> vec    
[1] "z[[letter[1]]]," "z[[letter[2]]]," "z[[letter[3]]]"
```

I want to use `vec` to order the rows of dataframe `z`, using the code below,

```
z.sort <- z[with(z, order(???)),]
```

How can I get the character vector `vec` to be evaluated as the arguments to `order`?
Is there a better way of doing this bearing in mind that `letter`, which is used to form `vec` will be an argument to a function?

Desired output would be:

```
    a  b  c
5   1  1  9
10  2 10  2
1   3  7  1
9   4  2  5
8   5  8  6
2   6  4  3
4   7  9 10
3   8  3  8
6   9  5  7
7  10  6  4
```

or as `dput` output:

```
structure(list(a = 1:10, b = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L), c = c(9L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 4L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(5L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It may be helpful if you provide a what the output should look like.

Comment: You should probably be moving that ??? argument to the right side of the comma, at least if you _are_ interested in re-ordering columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you want (with different random data):

```
> z[do.call(order, z[,letter]),]
    a  b  c
5   1  2  1
4   2  4  8
1   3  3  9
6   4  6  3
8   5  8  5
10  6  1  4
2   7  5  7
3   8 10  2
9   9  7  6
7  10  9 10
```

`do.call` lets us send a list to a function as its arguments, so we can just reorder the columns of `z` and send them to `order` using `do.call`, as a `data.frame` is just a special kind of list.

Works with no problem in a function:

```
my.reorder <- function(dat, cols) { dat[do.call(order, dat[,cols]),] }
```

Comment: Thanks, waay simpler than what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

A little more clarification about what your doing would help a lot, but a few thoughts...

in your `sapply` call you can simplify dramatically by using:

```
vec <- sapply(letter, function(x) paste('z[["',x,'"]]',sep=''))
```

the cat step is unnecessary unless you're trying to see the output as well as assign it... but you'd be better served there with a two line function that uses `print`.  you can get the sorting you're talking about by using `eval(parse(text=...))`

```
z[order(eval(parse(text=vec[1])),]
```

and getting each sorting out as a list:

```
lapply(vec, function(x) z[order(eval(parse(text=x))),])
```

But... if sorting your data.frame by the each column specified in letter is the goal:

```
lapply(letter, function(x) z[order(z[[x]]),])
```

gives you the same output as all the fiddly steps above.  Using something like `eval(parse(text=...))` often means you're doing something silly and should rethink your steps since there very well could be a more straightforward solution.