# Rank a list of models based on AIC values

Tags: r, model-comparison

After applying a model between one response variable and several exlanatory variables across a dataframe, I would like to rank each model by the AIC score. 
I have encountered a very similar question that does exactly what I want to do. 
[Using lapply on a list of models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172738/using-lapply-on-a-list-of-models), but it does not seem to work for me and I'm not sure why. Here's an example using the mtcars dataset:

```
lm_multiple <- lapply(mtcars[,-1], function(x) summary(lm(mtcars$mpg ~ x)))
```

An approved answer from the link above suggested:

```
sapply(X = lm_multiple, FUN = AIC)
```

But this does not work for me, I get this warning message.

> Error in UseMethod("logLik") :
>     no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "summary.lm"

Here is an answer from the original question...

```
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- sin(x)^2
model.list <- list(model1 = lm(y ~ x), 
               model2 = lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)))
sapply(X = model.list, FUN = AIC)
```

Comment: This exercise is futile. AIC is useful for comparing nested models that were fit to the same dataset. Your models are not nested.

Comment: @Roland thanks for the comment, what would be an alternative? p-values? In my dataset I have a large number (>100) explanatory variables

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this. You should probably ask on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160294/is-it-feasible-to-rank-several-unnested-generalized-additive-and-linear-models
Thanks, I actually just finished putting it there, it may be more clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove the `summary` like this

```
lm_multiple <- lapply(mtcars[,-1], function(x) lm(mtcars$mpg ~ x))
sapply(X = lm_multiple, FUN = AIC)
```