# Pass a named list of models to anova.merMod

Tags: r, lme4, anova, do.call

I want to be able to pass a named list of models (merMod objects) to anova() and preserve the model names in the output. This is particularly useful in the context of using mclapply() to run a batch of slow models like glmers more efficiently in parallel. The best I've come up with is to use do.call on a de-named version of the model list, but that's not ideal because I might have models named (say) "mod12", "mod17", and "mod16" and these model names get translated to "MODEL1", "MODEL2", and "MODEL3" in the output. (That might seem trivial when looking at a single batch, but over the course of a long modeling session with dozens of models it's a surefire recipe for confusion.)

Note that this isn't the same issue as [Create and Call Linear Models from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108045/create-and-call-linear-models-from-list) because I'm not trying to compare pairs of models across lists. It's also more complex than [Using lapply on a list of models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172738/using-lapply-on-a-list-of-models) because I'm using anova() in a non-unary way.

Here's a minimal reprex:

```
library(lme4)

formList <- c(mod12 = angle ~ recipe + temp + (1|recipe:replicate),
              mod17 = angle ~ recipe + temperature + (1|recipe:replicate),
              mod16 = angle ~ recipe * temperature + (1|recipe:replicate))
modList <- lapply(formList, FUN=lmer, data=cake)

# Fails because modList is named so it's interpreted as arg-name:arg pairs
do.call(anova, modList)

# Suboptimal because model names aren't preserved
do.call(anova, unname(modList))

# Fails because object isn't merMod (or some other class covered by methods("anova"))
do.call(anova, list(object=modList[1], ...=modList[-1], model.names=names(modList)))
```

The second do.call returns this:

```
Data: ..1
Models:
MODEL1: angle ~ recipe + temp + (1 | recipe:replicate)
MODEL2: angle ~ recipe + temperature + (1 | recipe:replicate)
MODEL3: angle ~ recipe * temperature + (1 | recipe:replicate)
       Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
MODEL1  6 1708.2 1729.8 -848.08   1696.2                          
MODEL2 10 1709.6 1745.6 -844.79   1689.6  6.5755      4     0.1601
MODEL3 20 1719.0 1791.0 -839.53   1679.0 10.5304     10     0.3953
```

Ideally, the output would look like this:

```
Data: ..1
Models:
mod12: angle ~ recipe + temp + (1 | recipe:replicate)
mod17: angle ~ recipe + temperature + (1 | recipe:replicate)
mod16: angle ~ recipe * temperature + (1 | recipe:replicate)
      Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
mod12  6 1708.2 1729.8 -848.08   1696.2                          
mod17 10 1709.6 1745.6 -844.79   1689.6  6.5755      4     0.1601
mod16 20 1719.0 1791.0 -839.53   1679.0 10.5304     10     0.3953
```

How do I do this? I'm more than happy with an ugly wrapper around anova() if it means I get a more intelligible output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a list of symbols like this:

```
with(modList,
     do.call(anova, 
             lapply(names(modList), as.name)))
#refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
#Data: ..1
#Models:
#mod12: angle ~ recipe + temp + (1 | recipe:replicate)
#mod17: angle ~ recipe + temperature + (1 | recipe:replicate)
#mod16: angle ~ recipe * temperature + (1 | recipe:replicate)
#      Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
#mod12  6 1708.2 1729.8 -848.08   1696.2                          
#mod17 10 1709.6 1745.6 -844.79   1689.6  6.5755      4     0.1601
#mod16 20 1719.0 1791.0 -839.53   1679.0 10.5304     10     0.3953
```

Comment: Ahhhh, good call on with(). I knew it had to be something to do with the environment. Thanks!